# swift 3 core data fetch results

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

i have a core data modal with the entity "Users"
There are two attributes "firstName" and "secondName"

this is actually my code to fetch the results:

```
var content:[String] = []


func RequestData() {


    let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Kunden")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {


                if let firstname = result.value(forKey: "firstname") as? String {

                    content.append(firstname)

                }

                if let secondname = result.value(forKey: "secondname") as? String {

                    content.append(secondname)

                }

            }


        }

        tbl_kunden.reloadData()


    } catch {

        print("ERROR")

    }


}
```

this works fine.
Problem is. I dont belive that

```
var content:[String] = []
```

is the correctly variable to take the results.
Because the output of print(content) is:

> ["Max", "Mustermann", "Max2", "Mustermann2", "Max3", "Mustermann3"]

Which variable type will be the best for this situation?

i think the result should be something like this:

```
+ID
++Max
++Mustermann

+ID
++Max2
++Mustermann2

+ID
++Max3
++Mustermann3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create custom `User` objects that are subclasses of `NSManagedObject`.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject

But if you don't need custom logic, you could change your variable to a `Int`:`[String]` `Dictionary`:

```
var content:[Int: [String]] = [:]
```

And append the data like this:

```
if let id = result.value(forKey: "firstname") as? Int {
    let firstName = result.value(forKey: "firstname") as? String ?? "Unknown"
    let secondName = result.value(forKey: "secondname") as? String ?? "Unknown"
    let user = [id: [firstName, lastName]]
    print("Fetched user: \(user.debugDescription)")
}
```

Comment: can you show me an example for subclasses of NSManagedObject? I dont know why, but i dont understand the apple docu